# Excel - Location and prioritisation of values in a range

Tags: excel-formula

Hi and thanks very much for taking the time to read/respond.

I'm struggling with trying to adapt a very advance formula given by **tigeravatar** here: [tigeravatar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133082/excel-formula-using-priority-rules-depending-on-range-inputs)

I have an almost identical issue, but have the following possible states:
A, B, C, D, and corresponding levels of priority.

In a given range, multiple entries in any of these four categories could be made. But I need to return only the highest value regardless of all other entries.

Here's the original formula.

```
=INDEX({"","D","C","B","A"},MATCH(SUMPRODUCT({4,3,2,1},--(COUNTIF('Sheet 002'!E29:E32,{"A","B","C","D"})>0)),{0,1,2,3,4}))
```

The only problem being that in the formula above if B and C co-occur it displays A, and if B and C only display if they occur in isolation.

Thanks in advance for your and any inputs you're willing to share!

Comment: Apologies - I should add  that the formula I've cited above is my adaptation of the original. Many thanks.W

Answer (score 0):

If you were willing to have a helper column, you could convert the letters to numbers using `=CODE()`.  This column can then be ranked by taking the minimum (A=65, B=66, etc.) Note that `CODE()` is case-sensitive.  You can find the highest ranking letter by using a formula like this:

`=INDEX(E29:E32,MATCH(MIN(F29:F32),F29:F32,0))`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBeOZ.png)